# Possibly fraudulent account (new account of previously-suspended user)

Tags: discussion, moderation, users, account-suspension

I have a suspicion that [the user who was suspended for voting irregularities](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1002260/steven-penny)  has created [a new account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4427511/sarah-manning) masking himself as a young girl (using the name and photo).

I wouldn't mind it if he won't be doing fishy edits to my answers (all edits were rejected or later reverted: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11053672), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11053412), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11053445)). His changes consist of **changing original links to a GitHub repository to point to the [GitHub repository of the suspended account](http://github.com/svnpenn/sage)**. That's why I'm confident, that the new account and previously suspended one are actually one and the same person.

I don't know if it violates Stack Overflow's rules anyhow. Also, the new account has upvoted answers so he's actually adding a value to the Stack Overflow, but it should be checked if he's not doing anything bad also somewhere else. I found out that some time ago I was already [reverting some weird edits](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23143936/revisions#spacer-c56806bf-63d5-4f46-a7b1-92aed11f2e15) to my answers made by the suspended account.

Should I take any action and if yes, what should I do? Or is it a proper behavior and any wrong-doing will be filtered out by reviews, etc.?

Comment: Flag it to a moderator and explain it? It doesn't really do much as a meta post... (side note : Sarah manning is a fictional character from a TV show... "Orphan Black", in case you're interested. Amazing show btw)

Comment: Flag a moderator.  There's nothing we mortals can do.

Comment: @Patrice Sorry, my answer was actually lacking an answer :) My intent with this question was to ask if I should do anything about that and what. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @DawidFerenczy Strange thing... If I follow the link to the github repository which was originally in your answers (https://github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg), I get a note that it is unavailable due to a DMCA.takedown.

Comment: @DawidFerenczy fair enough. I though you edited it to get further clarifications :P  I figured me and Makoto were pretty clear. But yeah, it is NOT okay to do, but mods are really the only people who can do something about it

Comment: @Patrice OK, it makes a sense. But **what** actually should I flag? I can't flag those edit reviews.

Comment: @DawidFerenczy A couple of options: One of the answers/questions you have he/she edited, or one of his/her questions/answers. Basically anywhere a mod can "get" the account from. And then try to explain as much as possible in the flag textbox (linking to this meta post may not be a bad move)

Comment: @Patrice Sounds good. Thank you for advices!

Comment: @Louis Yep, that's true, it's also mentioned in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260014/how-do-i-install-cygwin-components-from-the-command-line/23143997#23143997). I guess that DMCA takedown was initiated by the same person. I don't know why and with who is he fighting. His script is completely different from that one which is blocked now.

Comment: Use the custom flag and explain what you think is going on.

Comment: Done. Thank you for suggestions!

Comment: The DMCA take down was filed recently. Might be the same guy doing. Maybe other people just got this guy computer and play prank on it or something.

Comment: @CuriousSam:  It looks more like a feud to me.  User Steven Penny owns the Sage project, but he says [here](https://github.com/svnpenn/sage/issues/2) that he's the sole developer of apt-cyg, too.  Insert juicy speculation here.

Comment: regarding weird edits, you can flag posts damaged by these for mod attention and ask moderators to ban the editor and, _especially_, reviewers who approve their garbage

Comment: As others suggested, you need to flag it. Click the flag link below the question near share and edit(or answer), you get to see a model dialog, and you select the appropriate radio button.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Seems like the user has been destroyed by a moderator now.

For future reference, flag one of the posts they edited with a custom flag explaining the problem. The moderators are very good at finding patterns and sockpuppets, so it shouldn't take long normally.

Comment: Yep, I'm surprised how fast it was. I would say he was adding some value to the community actually (upvoted answers), so I hope he'll create an another account, but will stop doing bad or weird things. In such case, nobody will delete his account I guess.

Answer (score 6):

Sorry for the late reply, I wasn't aware of this post.

I looked at the linked repos and at the notice.

It was brought to [our attention](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/28404203#28404203) in the [SOCVR room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers). We came across this user making those edits to your post and asked [Ed Cottrell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2057919/ed-cottrell) for advice. He said they [should be rejected](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/28404415#28404415).

A few of us, including Ed, proceeded to go through the user's suggested edits and reject them.

In fact many posts with the [cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cygwin) were targeted.

'Sarah Manning' (the sock account) was brought into the room for a chat and Ed sent them a private message. I also asked Ed if it was okay to reverse the edits that had been approved, which I then did.

The things that pain me about this are twofold:

1. How was the notice put on the original GitHub repo to begin with?
2. How underhanded a person can be.

Comment: #2. So much #2.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and details. I'm not sure I understood what that person was doing. To me, he looks like a split schizophrenic person. On the GitHub, he claimed himself as a sole developer of the original repository to which he issued a DMCA takedown request. He had created a new repository, but the code there is completely different from the previous repository. It's just weird.

Comment: @DawidFerenczy that is weird... :/